# Adding column using SQL select

Tags: sql

My table currently looks like this

[image: Table1]

Is there a way that I can create a select statement that puts the table like this without changing the original table?

[image: Table2]

I currently have
SELECT ID, Word FROM Table WHERE Lang = 1 OR Lang = 2

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures.  Edit the question and put sample data as text.  Thanks

Comment: Yes . . . using `join`, or `pivot`, or conditional aggregation.  Which have you tried?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the temp table based around your table and enhanced @ImranRashid query below

```
create table #Language 
(
Id Int,
Lang Int,
word NVARCHAR(100)
)

Insert INTO #Language 
VALUES(1,1,'Hello');
Insert INTO #Language 
VALUES(1,2,'Bonjour');
Insert INTO #Language 
VALUES(2,1,'Thank you');
Insert INTO #Language 
VALUES(2,2,'Merci');
```

Now run below query to self join but make sure lang id is selected differently

```
SELECT 
g1.ID, g1.word as English, g2.word as French 
FROM 
#Language g1, #Language g2 
WHERE 
g1.ID = g2.Id AND g1.Lang = 1 AND g2.Lang=2;
```

ID  English French

---

1   Hello   Bonjour

2   Thank you   Merci

Now to test this with another word run below insert query

```
Insert INTO #Language 
VALUES(3,1,'Hi');
Insert INTO #Language 
VALUES(3,2,'Salut');
```

Run above query again 
Result below

ID  English French

---

1   Hello   Bonjour
2   Thank you   Merci
3   Hi  Salut

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a clear case of self join. I am assuming that your table name is "greetings". You can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
g1.ID, g1.word as English, g2.word as French 
FROM 
greetings g1, greetings g2 
WHERE 
g1.ID = g2.Lang;
```

Comment: This will only pick up if the table has only two words

Comment: Something like this 
SELECT 
g1.ID, g1.word as English, g2.word as French 
FROM 
#Language g1, #Language g2 
WHERE 
g1.ID = g2.Id AND g1.Lang = 1 AND g2.Lang=2;